# No puedo hacer ping de mi CentOS 7 virtual a mi Windows 10

Tags: linux, centos, ping

En mi windows 10 tengo instalado un CentOS 7 virtual a través de virtualbox.

Hasta ahora había trabajado solamente con la configuración de red "Adaptador solo-anfitrión", ahora deseo hacer ping de mi máquina virtual a mi windows 10. Siguiendo una par de tutoriales, cambié la configuración de red a "Adaptador Puente" que usa el controlador "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller", pero al hacer ping a mi windows 10 cuya dirección IP es 192.168.99.208 obtengo el error:

connect: Network is unreachable

al hacer el ifconfig obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: al hacer el ifconfig obtengo lo siguiente:]

Al ejecutar el comado ip route show, obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Por favor si alguien puede indicarme que necesito hacer. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, reemplaza la imagen por texto copiado/pegado. Podrías incluir la salida del siguiente comando en la pregunta: `ip route show`. Y a qué dirección estarías haciendo ping como el host güindous? Como último detalle, también deberías mostrar las IPs (por lo menos las no públicas) asignadas en el host windows y las rutas configuradas (no se qué comandos se usará hoy día para ello en güindous).

Comment: Se ha incluido la información resultante de ip route show. Estoy con dificultades para copiar y luego pegar el texto desde la máquina virtual. La ip del host es 192.168.99.208

Comment: Para que funcione puente necesitas un adaptador de red físico para el host y otro por cada invitado (ej. eth y wifi). Aunque con *Sólo anfitrión* te debería funcionar.

Comment: @sal.... eso es cierto con un host guindous? Porque con un host linux yo se que un host y un guest se pueden comunicar a través de un bridge (de los que se hacen con `brctl`, yo lo he hecho muchas veces con QEMU, supongo que algo parecido se debe poder hacer con virtualbox).

Comment: @eftshift0 Son conceptos diferentes

Comment: verifica la mascara de subred, por lo que se ve estarías filtrando solo el ultimo byte ( `255.255.255.0` ) y al parecer las redes son diferentes en el 3er octeto:  `192.168.122.xxx` una `192.168.99.xxx` la otra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes cambiar la máscara de red si lo que te interesa es tener una red más grande. Pero si no es así, y en caso de que no hayas asignado tu la IP de la máquina virtual(es decir, se ha asignado automáticamente por DHCP.) puedes cambiarle la IP por una del mismo segmento que tu máquina Windows(192.168.99.X).

Comment: Gracias. Mediante nmtui asigné manualmente la IP de mi Centos 7 cirtual. Le asigné 192.168.99..30/24. La IP de mi windows (host) es 192.168.99.208/24. Puse el mismo gateway para ambos 192.168.99.1 así como los servidores DNS 192.168.101.214 y 1.1.1.1

Comment: pero sigo sin poder hacer ping, hay algo más que debería modficar?

Comment: He resulto el problema usando tu consejo, simplemente habría que mencionar que una vez hecho el cambio de  IP se debe ejecutar: systemctl restart network.service, y tener cuidado también de que el modo de red del linux virtual este en adaptador puente

Comment: Así es! me alegro que hayas podido resolverlo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser la máscara de red de la máquina Windows 10, que tiene la máscara /16. No es lo mismo la red 192.168.1.X que las 192.168.X.X 
Échale un vistazo a la máscara de tu máquina Windows 10. 
Desde el gestor de archivos->Propiedades -> Ethernet(esta puede cambiar si es red WiFi) -> Propiedades(aparece el símbolo de administrador) -> Protocolo de Internet ipV4 -> Propiedades y hay escribes a mano la ip del equipo y la máscara /24

Comment: Gracias. Mediante nmtui asigné manualmente la IP de mi Centos 7 virtual. Le asigné 192.168.99..30/24. La IP de mi windows (host) es 192.168.99.208/24. Puse el mismo gateway para ambos 192.168.99.1 así como los servidores DNS 192.168.101.214 y 1.1.1.1, pero aun no puede hacer ping

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).